# launch an application stored on google drive

Tags: web-applications, google-drive-api, shell-exec

I'm building a little web app as a data store for a client.  User can navigate around the site and download the files they need.  I also have an .exe program stored and installed server side.  Is there a way they can click a link to launch that .exe from the server on their machine.  I've been through a couple of JS solutions using ShellExectue but no joy.  All of this is hosted on Google Drive at the moment (just for testing).  Linking to the .exe directly on G Drive brings up the option to save the .exe but that leaves all the .dll behind on G Drive and thus it doesn't work.

Any help appreciated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could provide a "download" link in your web app and send them a zip file with all the exe and dll files they need.

Or, you could look into technologies like ClickOnce deployment or Java Web Start, depending on your technology stack.

Note however that you'll always have to deal with security and permissions in a setup like this. If at all possible, try to move all the application logic into your web app so the users don't have to install anything.

Comment: Unfortunately it's not my app so there may be rights issues there.  For the moment I'm just directing them to the download page of the app (dnrgps if you're interested) but this would be a useful thing to be able to do regardless (and I generally feel like I've failed if I have to "workaround" ;) )

Comment: If it's a third-party app, there's probably not much you can do other than pointing users to the download page. If you're in an enterprise environment, check what other deployment vehicles they use.